# Web application with Angular CLI does not display bootstrap-sass glyphicons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-sass

I have an application I created with Angular CLI, and I am using `bootstrap-sass` to customize the theme. I am using the following versions...

```
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8
bootstrap-sass: 3.3.7
```

In my `.angular-cli.json` I have

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

In my `html` file I have

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

In my `scss` file I have

```
$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper: true;
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "../bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/");
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```

There are no errors when I run `ng serve` or `ng build` and the application runs correctly with no errors in the browser console. However, the icons still do not display. I originally had this application running with the glyphicons displaying properly, and then I migrated the core application code into a new `angular-cli` application. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Add a closing span tag <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>

Comment: try to put @import as first line.. any changes?

Comment: @ArrowHead, I had it in my code, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: @federico, It needs to be at the bottom.

Comment: if you do require("../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss") ??

Comment: @federico, It is properly importing bootstrap as far as I can tell, as it has all the correct css. The only issue is the glyphicons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the way `webpack` is [configured](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/597) within `angular-cli`. Currently you can workaround this by pointing to the bootstrap CDN fonts with the following in the `scss` file

```
$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper: false;
$icon-font-path: "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/";
```